# How do I get Date & Time widget in my system tray?

Tags: unity, indicator

Somehow I managed to remove the Date & Time widget from my system tray.  How do I get it back?  Also "Date & Time" no longer appears in System Settings.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Using Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Thankfully I no longer use unity, so I have no idea which answer is correct.

Answer (score 6):

Confirm that it is installed. The package is called *indicator-datetime*[image: indicator-datetime]. You can just click the link and it'll show you if it's installed or not. If it's not, then install it and log out and back in.

Comment: thanks, this added "Time & Date" settings back into my system.  However, the "Clock" tab in Time & Date is grayed out, so I still can't get the clock back in my menu bar.

Answer (score 1):

In 10.04 it is so: 
click panel with Your right mouse button and choose: add to panel, then You have to find a proper widget.
However i don't know if in 11.10 it works.

Comment: It works in 11.10 if you use Gnome Panel, but it doesn't work in Unity since that's a different panel.